# How to see if there is JQuery injected in an website through PhantomJS

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I need to use PhantomJS for some testing purposes and I need to detect if there is a JQuery library which has already been injected to the website or not. If there is, I don't want to inject it into the page in which I am going to do my stuff. If there is not, I would like to inject this library to my current page. I have following function:

```
function checkJQuery()
{
    return page.evaluate(function() 
    {
        return window.jQuery;
    });
}
```

Then, inside my functions, before each 'page.evaluate' I have following lines

```
if (!checkJQuery())
    page.injectJs("jquery.js");
```

I expect this function to return either 'true' or 'false'. But what I have is 'null'. What is wrong with my test here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for you...

```
var jQueryVersion;
jQueryVersion = page.evaluate(function () {
    return (typeof jQuery === 'function') ? jQuery.fn.jquery : undefined;
});

if (jQueryVersion) {
    // jquery exists
}
```